# TextField not working with euro sign

Tags: hyperref, textfield

The € is not working properly in `\TextField` in almost all pdf viewers.
I have a pdf document where the € sign is working in all pdf viewers, so the assumption is that the implemented `\TextField` is not working properly.

## Proof

As example I am using evince on debian.
If i click on a text field then all the text in the box is selected but the old text does not disappear (I assume that this is the default behavior of evince on debian):

[image]

If I input "is it working€?" in the properly implemented text field of the external pdf I get the behavior:

[image]

If I input "is it working€?" in the document created by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField{}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

then I get the behavior:

[image]

so the € is working in "writing mode", but not in "reading mode".

## Question

How do I get the € working like the external pdf document?

Comment: If you want to replicate a properly working text field in pdf you can use for example "Master PDF Editor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The euro is missing in the encoding declaration. You can patch hyperref like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\Hy@FormObjects{164/currency}{160/Euro 164/currency}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField{name}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]